# Android appcompat_v7 does not starts

Tags: android, classnotfoundexception, android-appcompat

i saw here similar problems, but no one could help me.
I'am using eclipse. In my project i use  RoundedImageView-master as library.
It means, that i have in eclipse "main" project without sources and "gen" folder with package-name: com.makeramen.roundedimageview
and i appcompat_v7-project with lib android-support-v7-appcompat.jar.

Withhin my layouts i´am using instead of "...res-auto" this:

```
 xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/lib/com.makeramen.roundedimageview"
```

In my Main-Activity i imported this:

```
import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarDrawerToggle;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.support.design.widget.NavigationView;
import android.support.design.widget.NavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener;
```

In my Buildpath into the section library appears my "main"-project.
Now i want to start my app, but i get from cat_log:

```
FATAL EXCEPTION: main
Process: com.hdd.myExampleApp, PID: 3454
java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to instantiate activity ComponentInfo{com.hdd.myExampleApp/com.hdd.myExampleApp.MainActivity}: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "com.hdd.myExampleApp.MainActivity" on path: DexPathList[[zip file "/data/app/com.hdd.myExampleApp-1/base.apk"],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/vendor/lib, /system/lib]]
    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2209)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2360)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:144)
    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1278)
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5221)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:899)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:694)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "com.hdd.myExampleApp.MainActivity" on path: DexPathList[[zip file "/data/app/com.hdd.myExampleApp-1/base.apk"],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/vendor/lib, /system/lib]]
    at dalvik.system.BaseDexClassLoader.findClass(BaseDexClassLoader.java:56)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:511)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:469)
    at android.app.Instrumentation.newActivity(Instrumentation.java:1065)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2199)
    ... 10 more
    Suppressed: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com.hdd.myExampleApp.MainActivity
        at dalvik.system.DexFile.defineClassNative(Native Method)
        at dalvik.system.DexFile.defineClass(DexFile.java:226)
        at dalvik.system.DexFile.loadClassBinaryName(DexFile.java:219)
        at dalvik.system.DexPathList.findClass(DexPathList.java:321)
        at dalvik.system.BaseDexClassLoader.findClass(BaseDexClassLoader.java:54)
        ... 14 more
    Suppressed: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.hdd.myExampleApp.MainActivity
        at java.lang.Class.classForName(Native Method)
        at java.lang.BootClassLoader.findClass(ClassLoader.java:781)
        at java.lang.BootClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:841)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:504)
        ... 13 more
    Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Class not found using the boot class loader; no stack available
```

and my Console says to me:

```
[myExampleApp] Android Launch!
[myExampleApp] adb is running normally.
[myExampleApp] Performing com.hdd.myExampleApp.MainActivity activity launch
[2myExampleApp] Uploading myExampleApp.apk onto device '192.168.56.101:5555'
[2myExampleApp] Installing myExampleApp.apk...
[myExampleApp] Success!
[myExampleApp] Project dependency found, installing: main
[main] Uploading main.apk onto device '192.168.56.101:5555'
[main] Installing main.apk...
[main] Success!
[myExampleApp] Starting activity com.hdd.myExampleApp.MainActivity on device 192.168.56.101:5555
[myExampleApp] ActivityManager: Starting: Intent { act=android.intent.action.MAIN cat=[android.intent.category.LAUNCHER] cmp=com.hdd.myExampleApp/.MainActivity }
```

i thought, that i have to include in my manifest something like this:

```
 <uses-library android:name="com.makeramen.roundedimageview"/>
```

This packagename appears on my gen-folder from main-project.
When i start this, i geht from my console:

```
[myExampleApp] Android Launch!
[myExampleApp] adb is running normally.
[myExampleApp] Performing com.hda.myExampleApp.MainActivity activity launch
[myExampleApp] Uploading myExampleApp.apk onto device '192.168.56.101:5555'
[myExampleApp] Installing myExampleApp.apk...
[myExampleApp] Installation error: INSTALL_FAILED_MISSING_SHARED_LIBRARY
[myExampleApp] Please check logcat output for more details.
[myExampleApp] Launch canceled!
```

i dont have ideas anymore, what could i do.
Please help me :)

Answer (score 0):

You must using just `xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"` and
android himself found relative resource.

Comment: no i cant do that. When i include "res-auto", so Eclipse does not find any attributs, which i use.